# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]

Tags: java, android, linux, security, adb

There is an error launching `activity`, unfortunately I assume it is not connected strictly with the project due to the fact the app launches on `genymotion` emulator, but does not on physical device.

When I run `adb devices` with the real one connected i get:

```
List of devices attached 
0009215b1eef4f  device
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` has not any permissions required set and device has sufficient `api version`.

Regards

Comment: This can also happen if you  have added `android:exported="false"` in Manifest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was with Launcher selection in Android Studio. To improve testing speed of application module there was selected other Activity as `Launcher`(in run properties) than specified in manifest.xml. Strange that it worked even on emulator..

The solution is simply to change the Launcher to the one set in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Correct, running specified activity won't help if we want to test particular activity for no. of times ... instead using your solution and running app helps better :) thanks for hint!

Answer (score 10):

Simply add:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

on *AndroidManifest.xml* into the tag:

```
<activity>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Correct, running specified activity won't help if we want to test particular activity for no. of times ... instead using your solution and running app helps better :) thanks for hint!

Answer (score 5):

As @Tushar Gogna said in the comment.

> "This can also happen if you have added android:exported="false" in
> Manifest"

Adding this as the answer, since it worked for me.